# Combobox value isn't captured using ng -model when inside a table generated by ng -repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, html, controller

This is my code

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Id Detalle_Venta</th>
  <th>Id Producto</th>
  <th>Producto </th>
  <th>Cantidad </th>
  <th>Direccion </th>                            
  <th>Repartidor </th>                            
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="det in detalleVenta">
  <td>{{det.id_Detalle_Venta}}</td>
  <td>{{det.id_Producto}}</td>
  <td>{{det.nombre_Producto}} {{det.formato}}</td>
  <td>{{det.cantidad}}</td>
  <td>{{det.direccion}}</td>
  <td>
    <select name="test" class="form form-control" ng-model="comboRepartidor" ng-change="escogerRepartidor()">
     <option class="form form-control" id="idRepartidor" ng-repeat="rep in repartidores" value="{{rep.id_Repartidor}}">{{rep.nombre}}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is in this lines:

```
    <select name="test" class="form form-control" ng-model="comboRepartidor" ng-change="escogerRepartidor()">
      <option class="form form-control" id="idRepartidor" ng-repeat="rep in repartidores" value="{{rep.id_Repartidor}}">{{rep.nombre}}</option>
    </select>
```

Angular doesn't capture the value of select with the `ng-model="comboRepartidor"`. The event `ng-change="escogerRepartidor()` shoud be show de combo value but it show Undefined. If I move the combo out of the table works fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edited for clarity:
The problem in this case is that `ng-repeat` creates child scopes for each item.

`comboRepartidor` is in the scope of the controller, so when you place `<select>` outside the table, `ng-model` will be bound to that scope.

`ng-repeat` directive creates a number of items, each one having its own scope that inherits from the parent scope. `comboRepartidor` property in the parent scope will be visible in every one of these child scopes; however, when you change the selection of any of the dropdowns, `ng-model` of that will assign a property "comboRepartidor" in its own scope.

This is because scopes in angular are based on javascript prototype "inheritance".

See more about that: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/nGCeSXsNcYk

You can fix it, for example, by binding the model to a property in the item `"det"` of the array `detalleVenta`.